# Reasoning for the DOF of $\frac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \mu)^2 \sim \chi_n^2$ and $\frac{1}{\sigma^2} n(\bar{Y} - \mu)^2 \sim \chi_1^2$?

Tags: degrees-of-freedom, chi-squared-distribution

I have the following example:

> Let $Y_1, \dots, Y_n$ be an i.i.d. $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$. Note that $\sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \mu)^2 = \sum_{i = 1}^n (y_i - \bar{y})^2 + n(\bar{y} - \mu)^2$.
>
> We show that $\sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \sim \sigma^2 \chi^2_{n - 1}$.
>
> By the equality
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \mu)^2 = \dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 + \dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} n(\bar{Y} - \mu)^2,$$
>
> we have that the left-hand side is
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \mu)^2 \sim \chi_n^2,$$
>
> and the term in the right-hand side is
>
> $$\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} n(\bar{Y} - \mu)^2 \sim \chi_1^2,$$
>
> and so $$\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \sim \chi_{n - 1}^2$$

The result $\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \sim \chi_{n - 1}^2$ matches with what I found in [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution#Sum_of_squares_of_independent_identically_distributed_normal_random_variables_minus_their_mean) Wikipedia article, but what is the reasoning for the degrees of freedom of $\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \mu)^2 \sim \chi_n^2$ and $\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} n(\bar{Y} - \mu)^2 \sim \chi_1^2$?

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for the comment. But these variables are $N(\mu, \sigma^2)$, not $\mathcal N(0,1)$. Or am I misunderstanding something here?

Comment: @Xi'an Oh, yes, we actually have $(Y_i - \mu)^2$, so it is indeed $\mathcal N(0,1)$. And this part of the Wikipedia article answers my main question: "In probability theory and statistics, the chi-square distribution (also chi-squared or $\chi^2$-distribution) with $k$ degrees of freedom is the distribution of a sum of the squares of $k$ independent standard normal random variables."

Comment: @Xi'an But something I still don't understand is why $\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \bar{Y})^2 \sim \chi_{n - 1}^2$ has $n - 1$ degrees of freedom, whereas $\dfrac{1}{\sigma^2} \sum_{i = 1}^n (Y_i - \mu)^2 \sim \chi_n^2$ has $n$ degrees of freedom. If I hadn't read this https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-square_distribution#Sum_of_squares_of_independent_identically_distributed_normal_random_variables_minus_their_mean part of the Wikipedia article, I would naively think that they should both be $n$ degrees of freedom.

Comment: The terms $Y_i-\bar Y$ are _dependent_ since they satisfy the identity$$\sum_i (Y_i-\bar Y)=0$$with probability one. This relation removes one degree of freedom.

Comment: @Xi'an Ahh, ok, that makes sense. Thanks for the clarification! I guess that answers everything.